# No Adobe Reader PDF Preview in Outlook after Update in November

Tags: microsoft-outlook, adobe-reader, preview

I used to have the possibility to quickly open a preview of a .pdf file in Outlook. Adobe Reader is my standard .pdf viewer in the background. After an update by Adobe in November there was no preview in the Windows Explorer - which I was able to fix - and no preview in Outlook.

In the German version of Outlook the error massage reads: "Für die Datei kann keine Vorschau angezeigt werden, weil die zugehörige Vorschau nicht installiert ist.", which translates to: "For this file no preview can be shown, because the corresponding preview is not installed.".

[image]

Does anybody have a simple way of fixing this?

Thanks in advance!

Timon

PS:
Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12130.20232) 32-Bit
Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, Continuous Release, Version 2021.007.20099, 64-Bit

Comment: I am writing to see if there is any progress on the issue. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> PS: Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12130.20232) 32-Bit Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, Continuous Release, Version 2021.007.20099, 64-Bit

As I know, if we install different bit of Microsoft Outlook and Adobe Reader, such as 32bit version of Microsoft Outlook with 64bit version of Adobe Reader or 64bit version of Microsoft Outlook with 32bit version of Adobe Reader, we may encounter many problems.

Considering the impact of this, It's suggested that you could uninstall one of the two program and reinstall with the same bit version as the other program to confirm the Microsoft Outlook and Adobe Reader are designed for the same architecture (32bit vs 64bit).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.